# date_trunc per day returns multiple rows for the same date

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I using date_trunc in order to count events per day. I have a subquery that I use the date_trunc on. The problem is that the query returns multiple rows per one date. Any ideas?

```
select 
    date_trunc('day',date_) date_,
    count(download),
    count(subscribe)
from
(select 
    min(users.redshifted_at) date_,
    users.id_for_vendor download,
    subs.id_for_vendor subscribe
from Facetune2_device_info_log users
left join Facetune2_usage_store_user_subscribed subs 
on users.id_for_vendor=subs.id_for_vendor
group by users.id_for_vendor,subs.id_for_vendor) b
group by date_
order by date_
```

Answer (score 1):

`date_` is confusing, because it is both a column and an alias.  Columns get resolved first.  So this should fix your problem:

```
group by date_trunc('day', date_)
```

You can also fix it by using a different alias name, one not already used for a column.